# In my classes, what should I change the cout/cin things with?

Tags: c++, class, oop, tostring

So basically I've just wrote my program with simple code using cout/cin in my one of my class methods(functions). I know it's bad and shouldn't be done, what should I switch them with?

For example right now I have class Human. It has some fields (variables) like gender, height, age.

I got a method called getInfo() and it's basically a lot of

```
cout << "Whats your age?" << endl;
cin >> age;
```

And so on. What should I change them to? Should I use something like

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream &o, const Human &s) 
istream& operator>>(istream &i, Human &s)
```

I have these functions written down but they're basically just for toString or not?

And what should I use toString for? (Need to have toString - task for my project thingy).

Comment: the overloaded operators will behave like getInfo() and toString methods? why isnt it ok for you to just ask the info from methods and cin/cout?

Comment: Well, toString() method is generally used to format and display output in string. You can use overloaded operators '<<' and '>>' within it.

Comment: The answer depends on what you really need (or have been asked) to do... I would start by "decoupling" the class that contains data (Human) and the way you get that data from user and assign it to the Human objects.  toString() method may just format the Human information (age, name, ...) into a std::string that can be outputted to somewhere outside the Human class (mind you this is really ugly C++ in my opinion,  it's way better to provide operator<<(std::ostream&)

Comment: I personally would ask to input the information in main function and use setName etc to assign it to the object, however I have another class called MealPlanner and one of the tasks is to use composition with another class. So I create the Human object inside Meal Planner and can't really get any information inside main.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `getInfo` generic on the input and output streams, e.g.:

```
void Human::getInfo(std::istream& input, std::ostream& output) {
    output << "What's your age?" << std::endl;
    input >> age;
    // etc.
}
```

`toString`s usually return a string representation of the object, so it could look something like this:

```
std::string Human::toString() const {
    std::string string;
    string += "Human(\n";
    string += "    age: " + std::to_string(age) + "\n";
    // etc.
    string += ")";
    return string;
}
```